# I'm trying to make a simple math thing but it gives me an error

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm trying to make a simple math thing that when you give the right answer it says 'correct' and when you get it wrong it says 'wrong'; however, it gives an error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\yu.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry'

and here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import tkinter.messagebox as tkm

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('my tk')

window.geometry('550x450')

def math1():

    e = tk.Tk()

    e.geometry('200x150')

    tk.Label(e, text = '10', height = 2).pack()

    tk.Label(e, text = '+ 12', height = 2).place(x=80, y=25)

    er = tk.StringVar()

    def check(entry):

        if entry == 22:

            tkm.showinfo('correct', 'correct!')

        else:

            tkm.showerror('try again', 'wrong, try again')
            
    entry = tk.Entry(e, textvariable = er)

    entry.place(x=90,y=60)

    tk.Button(e, text = 'submit', command = check).place(x=80, y = 80)

tk.Button(window, text='1', command = math1).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to `import tkinter as tk`, otherwise `tk` is undefined.

Next, your line here:

```py
tk.Button(e, text = 'submit', command = check).place(x=80, y = 80)
```

should be replaced with:

```py
tk.Button(e, text = 'submit', command = lambda: check(int(entry.get()))).place(x=80, y = 80)
```

Let me explain how this works.

1. You can't just pass `check` to the button, since `check` requires an `entry` parameter. You can get around this by defining a `lambda` function that calls `check(entry)`.
2. To get the input from the `entry` widget, you do `entry.get()`; however, since `entry` stores the input as a string, you must convert it to an integer using `int()` in order to compare it to 22.

The full code is below:

```py
import tkinter.messagebox as tkm
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('my tk')

window.geometry('550x450')

def math1():

    e = tk.Tk()

    e.geometry('200x150')

    tk.Label(e, text = '10', height = 2).pack()

    tk.Label(e, text = '+ 12', height = 2).place(x=80, y=25)

    er = tk.StringVar()

    def check(entry):

        if entry == 22:

            tkm.showinfo('correct', 'correct!')

        else:

            tkm.showerror('try again', 'wrong, try again')
            
    entry = tk.Entry(e, textvariable = er)

    entry.place(x=90,y=60)

    tk.Button(e, text = 'submit', command = lambda: check(int(entry.get()))).place(x=80, y = 80)

tk.Button(window, text='1', command = math1).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would recommend to format the code per PEP8 so it looks more readable.

Comment: @CoolCloud I just formatted it the same way that the OP did so as not to confuse him/her.

Comment: also im a him       .

Comment: I would suggest to get the content of `entry` inside `check()` function and use `try / except` to cater invalid input (i.e. user inputs something which is not a valid integer).

Comment: @WaltFu If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.